# Query to populate a column in MS Access based on the Maximum value of another column

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, max

This is my table `[Property]:`

```
Loanno  Balance amount  PropertyType
-------------------------------------
1001045 308731.770000     1
1001045 2007700.740000    2
1001045 3087318905.770    3
1001045 308731.770000     4
1001046 306589.67         1
1001046 456321.23         1
1001046 6932542.89        1
1001047 965421.34         Null
1001047 965421.34         2
1001048 567894.34         1
1001048 567894.34         2
```

I have to get the property type for a `[Loanno]` having highest `balance amount`. If there is a tie in the highest `balance amount` and if the `Property type` for the `loannumber` is different then for that `Loan number` I have to populate `property type` as '8'. So my final Output should look like this:

```
Loanno  PropertyType
---------------------
1001045     3
1001046     1
1001047     1
1001048     8
```

This is the query I tried.This was suggested by @Gord.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Property].Loanno, 
    IIf(Loanno_MaxBalance_Count.RowCount>1, 8, [Property].PropertyType) AS PropertyType
FROM 
    [Property]
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            [Property].Loanno, 
            [Property].[Balance amount], 
            COUNT(*) AS RowCount 
        FROM 
            [Property]
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT 
                    Loanno, 
                    MAX([Balance amount]) AS MaxBalance 
                FROM [Property] 
                GROUP BY Loanno
            ) AS Loanno_MaxBalance
                ON Loanno_MaxBalance.Loanno=[Property].Loanno 
                    AND Loanno_MaxBalance.MaxBalance=[Property].[Balance amount]
        GROUP BY [Property].Loanno, [Property].[Balance amount]
    ) AS Loanno_MaxBalance_Count
        ON [Property].Loanno=Loanno_MaxBalance_Count.Loanno 
            AND [Property].[Balance amount]=Loanno_MaxBalance_Count.[Balance amount]
```

But the problem here is for `Loan no` **1001047**, the highest `Balance amount` **965421.34** is having `Property type` as **1** and **NULL**. So for this, the above query is returning `property type` as **8**. Instead I want it to be 1. In general for the highest `balance amount` if the `Property type` is different and if it is not null I want **8** . Otherwise the `property type` should be a non NULL value. 
Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select LoanNo,
       iif(min(PropertyType) = max(PropertyType), min(PropertyType), 8) as PropertyType
from property as p inner join
     (select LoanNo, max(BalanceAmount) as maxba
      from property
      group by LoanNo
     ) as pmax
     on p.LoanNo = pmax.LoanNo and p.BalanceAMount = pmax.maxba
group by LoanNo;
```

Comment: No, My requirement is for the loan number,the property type corresponding to the Maximum balance amount should be populated. If the property type is different?(apart from NULL) for the Maximum balance amount then 8 should be populated.The above query is populating 8 even when the Maximum balance amount is different.

Comment: @user2416710 . . . Try it with the enhanced `on` clause.  I left out half the `join` conditions.